# significance of timestamp attribute in azure resource manager API response

Tags: azure

what does the timestamp attribute in the response body obtained after accessing the azure resource management API for listing the deployment by resource name signify?

Answer (score 0):

well, time when the request was done. i think its more of a good practice it doesnt necessary have any value to you in "everyday life", but when you are debugging something it might be useful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/380144)

Comment: this is an extremely vague question with no real answer, so i suppose this is the best he can get with such a question